# Need guidance on adding gcov support to a custom bootloader (u-boot as a reference)

Tags: linux, code-coverage, embedded-linux, u-boot, gcov

My question is regarding addition of **gcov** support to a custom bootloader, but lets start with `u-boot` for now.

I am taking `gcov support in Linux kernel` as a reference.

Need some pointers on bootloader specifics from coverage point of view.

Any traps and pitfalls I need to watch-out for ..

Comment: I am nowhere near being an expert about boot-loaders but I feel that this question is incredibly broad. Can you maybe narrow it down?

Comment: @ 5gon12eder: I am looking from code coverage point of view, so I am looking at [1] parts of u-boot which can/can't be instrumented and [2] some pointers on gcov support; the way its done in Linux kernel